# Complicated data structure union

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists of the following form:

```
lst1 = [{u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 15, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 7223.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 11, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 4503.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 18, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 6273.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 12, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 37550.0}], u'DayOfWeek': 1}, {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 9, u'TotalVisits': 50, u'TotalTimeSpent': 0.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 19, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 7925.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 14, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 4873.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 0, u'TotalVisits': 5, u'TotalTimeSpent': 10210.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 11, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 21825.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 8, u'TotalVisits': 19, u'TotalTimeSpent': 0.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 9, u'TotalVisits': 8, u'TotalTimeSpent': 13055.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 16, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 2816.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 11, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 15723.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 13, u'TotalVisits': 9, u'TotalTimeSpent': 30987.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 10, u'TotalVisits': 11, u'TotalTimeSpent': 68384.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 15, u'TotalVisits': 26, u'TotalTimeSpent': 62650.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 12, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 8626.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 17, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 34456.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 16, u'TotalVisits': 5, u'TotalTimeSpent': 6915.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 15, u'TotalVisits': 5, u'TotalTimeSpent': 3151.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 3, u'TotalVisits': 8, u'TotalTimeSpent': 54720.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 19, u'TotalVisits': 6, u'TotalTimeSpent': 23497.0}], u'DayOfWeek': 2}, {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 11, u'TotalVisits': 56, u'TotalTimeSpent': 0.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 8, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 4418.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 11, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 9952.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 9, u'TotalVisits': 5, u'TotalTimeSpent': 12678.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 10, u'TotalVisits': 11, u'TotalTimeSpent': 89911.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 22, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 0.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 14, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 1593.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 12, u'TotalVisits': 10, u'TotalTimeSpent': 36453.0}], u'DayOfWeek': 3}, {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 13, u'TotalVisits': 22, u'TotalTimeSpent': 0.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 13, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 4800.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 12, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 212.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 10, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 13503.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 14, u'TotalVisits': 7, u'TotalTimeSpent': 19533.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 11, u'TotalVisits': 5, u'TotalTimeSpent': 17512.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 22, u'TotalVisits': 14, u'TotalTimeSpent': 0.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 16, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 6121.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 9, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 5455.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 15, u'TotalVisits': 7, u'TotalTimeSpent': 21476.0}], u'DayOfWeek': 4}, {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 15, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 12697.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 11, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 10656.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 9, u'TotalVisits': 5, u'TotalTimeSpent': 11879.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 8, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 924.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 19, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 8075.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 10, u'TotalVisits': 20, u'TotalTimeSpent': 15478.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 12, u'TotalVisits': 6, u'TotalTimeSpent': 24608.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 14, u'TotalVisits': 8, u'TotalTimeSpent': 12858.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 13, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 2545.0}], u'DayOfWeek': 5}, {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 19, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 426.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 14, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 1528.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 12, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 11558.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 4, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 0.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 16, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 771.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 13, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 2449.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 15, u'TotalVisits': 17, u'TotalTimeSpent': 67983.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 11, u'TotalVisits': 5, u'TotalTimeSpent': 1452.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 10, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 5075.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 8, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 4769.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 9, u'TotalVisits': 14, u'TotalTimeSpent': 49453.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 10, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 0.0}], u'DayOfWeek': 6}, {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 17, u'TotalVisits': 8, u'TotalTimeSpent': 0.0}], u'DayOfWeek': 7}]  
lst2 = [{u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 15, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 425.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 13, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 730.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 16, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 70.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 8, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 240.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 10, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 295.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 2, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 1572.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 11, u'TotalVisits': 10, u'TotalTimeSpent': 1856.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 18, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 232.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 12, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 115.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 23, u'TotalVisits': 7, u'TotalTimeSpent': 1409.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 22, u'TotalVisits': 6, u'TotalTimeSpent': 1364.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 14, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 5.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 19, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 12.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 3, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 127.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 12, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 107.0}], u'DayOfWeek': 1}, {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 16, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 9.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 12, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 77.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 10, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 16.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 6, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 37.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 14, u'TotalVisits': 5, u'TotalTimeSpent': 956.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 9, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 787.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 8, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 27.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 18, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 24.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 19, u'TotalVisits': 7, u'TotalTimeSpent': 1123.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 18, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 108.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 9, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 39.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 17, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 28.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 22, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 117.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 13, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 65.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 21, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 870.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 20, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 42.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 11, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 10.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 23, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 98.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 8, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 3.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 7, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 14.0}], u'DayOfWeek': 2}, {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 7, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 21.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 2, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 11.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 22, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 13.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 10, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 4.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 16, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 4.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 13, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 112.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 19, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 148.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 11, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 10.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 20, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 15.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 8, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 85.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 0, u'TotalVisits': 10, u'TotalTimeSpent': 1634.0}], u'DayOfWeek': 3}, {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 22, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 1747.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 16, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 3.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 23, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 123.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 14, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 28.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 0, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 261.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 20, u'TotalVisits': 6, u'TotalTimeSpent': 22.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 11, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 5.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 19, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 131.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 8, u'TotalVisits': 10, u'TotalTimeSpent': 719.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 17, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 2.0}], u'DayOfWeek': 4}, {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 21, u'TotalVisits': 5, u'TotalTimeSpent': 550.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 9, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 0.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 11, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 12.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 0, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 58.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 17, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 95.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 7, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 841.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 22, u'TotalVisits': 9, u'TotalTimeSpent': 276.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 14, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 129.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 8, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 80.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 15, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 98.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 11, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 35.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 19, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 119.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 23, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 32.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 20, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 322.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 21, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 0.0}], u'DayOfWeek': 5}, {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 17, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 8.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 18, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 496.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 12, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 8.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 0, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 10.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 21, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 222.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 20, u'TotalVisits': 6, u'TotalTimeSpent': 196.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 16, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 98.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 2, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 201.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 22, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 653.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 10, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 16.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 15, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 92.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 23, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 29.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 23, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 182.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 8, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 430.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 8, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 548.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 17, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 40.0}], u'DayOfWeek': 6}, {u'Hours': [{u'HourOfDay': 22, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 70.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 19, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 120.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 14, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 413.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 11, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 806.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 10, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 26.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 0, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 840.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 1, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 46.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 23, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 252.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 21, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 99.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 7, u'TotalVisits': 1, u'TotalTimeSpent': 771.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 8, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 44.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 9, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 123.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 15, u'TotalVisits': 4, u'TotalTimeSpent': 661.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 12, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 309.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 18, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 77.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 13, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 123.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 3, u'TotalVisits': 3, u'TotalTimeSpent': 5324.0}, {u'HourOfDay': 20, u'TotalVisits': 2, u'TotalTimeSpent': 45.0}], u'DayOfWeek': 7}]
```

I want to add the total time spent in these two lists and create a new list out of it i.e. if HourOfDay for the same DayOfWeek is the same then add the TotalTimeSpent else append the info to the Hours list.

I have tried this but it doesn't run!

```
for item1, item2 in zip(lst1,lst2):
    for hr1 in item1["Hours"]:
        for hr2 in item2["Hours"]:
            if hr1["HourOfDay"] == hr2["HourOfDay"]:
                hr1["TotalTimeSpent"] = hr1["TotalTimeSpent"] + hr2["TotalTimeSpent"]
            else:
                item1["Hours"].append(hr2)
```

What I want is the union of the two lists for every day and if the HourOfDay field is the same for the two sets on the same dayOfWeek, then add the totalvisits and totaltimespent.

Comment: Could you be more specific than *"doesn't run"*?

Comment: I think it gets stuck in the loop because it doesn't give an output. I tried debugging it as well to no rescue!

Comment: How did you try debugging it? Have you put a `print` in the loop to check your theory?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't even print item1 and item2.

Comment: Then why do you think it's stuck in the loop? If it's not printing inside the loop, it's not entering the loop.

Comment: As tip: Next time provide only part of your data set. These list are incredibly long right now and this makes it hard to read them. If they are a bit smaller you could easily indent them and it makes it a lot easier for the people trying to help you.

Comment: Because I tried printing zip(list1,list2) right before the loop.

Comment: @RemcoW I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: I think it is much better if you do it step by step using functional programming, start with concat, then you can filter, reduce and map to get what you want.

Comment: @e-nouri how do you think that's going to help? Where is `concat` supposed to be coming from?

Comment: @e-nouri I want the same structure of list.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you help?

Comment: Please read [ask] then [edit] the question to include a [mcve].

Comment: It's very easy to comment!

Comment: As others have suggested, try using print statements in each of your for loops. I think it will be clearer what is happening. (Note that you are modifying the list over which you are iterating in one of your loops.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to comment, so I'll write my concerns here.

First off, I'm guessing that the missing indent level on the second for loop is a typo and that it doesn't appear in your original code.

Secondly, I don't understand the meaning of your else statement.

What you are, essentially, doing, is creating an infinite loop.

What that means is that your code, for every HOUR of first list you scan the second list looking for a match.

If a match is found, you update hr1 (careless of the fact that it is basically a "cursor", so it's going to be fairly useless once out of the loop), otherwise you APPEND an element to the end of the ORIGINAL list?

Keep in mind that you're scanning the original list, not a copy.

I wrote this piece of code real quick, give it a try and let me know:

```
final = lst1[::]
broken = False
i = j = 0
for item1, item2 in zip(lst1,lst2):
    # Backup copy
    it2_hrs = item2["Hours"]
    # Scan first list
    for hr1 in item1["Hours"]:
        # Scan second list
        for index,hr2 in enumerate(item2["Hours"]):
            print "index: {0} ;; hr2: {1}".format(index,hr2)
            if hr1["HourOfDay"] == hr2["HourOfDay"]:
                final[i]["Hours"][j]["TotalTimeSpent"] = hr1["TotalTimeSpent"] + hr2["TotalTimeSpent"]
                it2_hrs.pop(index)
                j += 1
                broken = True
                break
        if broken == True:
            broken = False
            continue
    final[i]["Hours"].extend(it2_hrs)
    i += 1
    j = 0
    break

print final
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks Guerriky, this only puts in those values in final where HourOfDay for lst1 and lst2 match. Not otherwise, if there is no match I want to include the other values in lst1 and lst2 as they are. How should I go about that?

Comment: On second thoughts, it doesn't include values that are present in lst2 and not in lst1.

Comment: Hey! I tried working on your code further but couldn't get the required solution.

Comment: Could you please suggest something?

Comment: Hi @Blabber. Please check edited code. I tested it real quick, and it seems to be working fine to me.